# Iterating through multi-dimentional lists while remembering indices

Tags: python, list, iteration

I have 4-dimentional array that stores values of points in 5-dimentional feature space. Luckily all features can be described by integer numbers, starting from 0 (therefore, can be coded by list indexes). When I process my data I do something like this (note that I need not only the values, but also all the corresponding features):

```
for f1 in range(len(data)):
    for f2 in range(len(data[f1])):
        for f3 in range(len(data[f1][f2])):
            for f4 in range(len(data[f1][f2][f3])):
                for f5 in range(len(data[f1][f2][f3][f4])):
                    value = data[f1][f2][f3][f4][f5]
                    process_point(f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, value)
```

However, this looks a bit ugly, owing to the high level of nesting. Is there a way to refactor this code in order to reduce nesting? There are different implementations of flatten function; however, they are designed to keep only values, but not indexes It would be also great, if the solution does not result in substantial decrease in performance.

Comment: If you really want to refactor - A single dictionary with tuples of length 5 serving as keys seems like a good way to avoid having a nervous breakdown when trying to access your data.

Comment: Using recursion maybe.

Comment: Could you post some input data example?

Comment: @MauroBaraldi  This is in fact very massive. But they are just float values assigned to integer coordinates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make the code look a little bit better, you can use `enumerate`:

```
for f1, d1 in enumerate(data):
    for f2, d2 in enumerate(d1):
        for f3, d3 in enumerate(d2):
            for f4, d4 in enumerate(d3):
                for f5, value in enumerate(d4):
                    process_point(f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, value)
```

A more general approach based on recursion could remove the nesting:

```
def access(d):
    if type(d) == list:
        for f, v in enumerate(d):
            for r in access(v):
                yield [f] + r
    else:
        yield [d]
```

Example usage:

```
a = \ # 4 levels deep only, don't want to have nightmares with lists tonight
[
    [
        [
            [1, 2, 3],
        ],
        [
            [11, 22, 33],
        ],
    ],
    [
        [
            [111, 222, 333],
        ],
    ],
    [
        [
            [1111, 2222, 3333],
        ],
    ],
]

for arg in access(a):
    process_point(*arg)
```

The `arg` that gets unpacked into the function `process_points` will be among this list:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 2],
 [0, 0, 0, 2, 3],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 11],
 [0, 1, 0, 1, 22],
 [0, 1, 0, 2, 33],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 111],
 [1, 0, 0, 1, 222],
 [1, 0, 0, 2, 333],
 [2, 0, 0, 0, 1111],
 [2, 0, 0, 1, 2222],
 [2, 0, 0, 2, 3333]]
```

That being said, the building up of the argument list in the recursive approach is not very efficient. If you can modify your code more wildly, you probably want to consider the a better representation of the data, such as one based on dictionary, as pointed out in the comments.

Comment: This does not reduce nesting

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comment. Tuples of ints can be iterated over easily enough, especially using itertools. They can be sorted by lex order (e.g. (0,1,3) < (0,1,4)). If you create data with `data = dict()` then any line in your code which looks like

```
data[i][j][k][l][m] = v
```

can be replaced by

```
data[(i,j,k,l,m)] = v
```

or even just (via implicit tuple formation)

```
data[i,j,k,l,m] = v
```

The following code snippet shows some of the possibilities:

```
import itertools
import random

data = dict()

points = list(itertools.product(range(0,9), repeat = 5))

rand_points = random.sample(points,10)
rand_points.sort() # in standard lex order

for p in rand_points:
    data[p] = random.random()

def process(point,value):
    print(str(point) + " maps to " +str(value))

for point in rand_points:
    process(point,data[point])
```

My (random) output:

```
(0, 3, 8, 2, 6) maps to 0.815091491066791
(0, 5, 6, 6, 1) maps to 0.25432836286289706
(0, 6, 8, 1, 5) maps to 0.4797033192218453
(2, 7, 1, 1, 6) maps to 0.9141711104231289
(4, 4, 6, 8, 7) maps to 0.016541794083792083
(4, 7, 3, 4, 3) maps to 0.42496849947725746
(5, 1, 5, 8, 1) maps to 0.4475971644821247
(6, 6, 6, 6, 1) maps to 0.40198989791011164
(7, 6, 7, 6, 3) maps to 0.9720480406273648
(8, 5, 4, 8, 0) maps to 0.8147848652511576
```

Note the complete absence of nested loops. Any effort on your part to master itertools is invaluable since it is a powerful but under-utilized module.